# Swift Class name & method name same issue

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ClassA {

}

class ClassB {

    func ClassA() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    var test = ClassA()
}
```

Assume situation like I need to create a object from *ClassA*. But in current class there is a method having same class name. which is *ClassA*.

So how can we create a instance from classA within classB? currently I am inside classB. Here variable test by default take function name, not the class name.

Comment: Check your code format, its really messed up, and the question is not very clearly written. Honestly, I would recommend just changing the name of the method `func ClassA() -> Bool` to something different. In my opinion having everything named the same like that can get very confusing.

Comment: Stick with conventions and name your function `classA` instead of `ClassA`. Also you can't invoke a function like that anyway, so your code isn't valid.

Comment: ClassA and func ClassA show have same name. That is my question. If those two having same name how can we differentiate?

Comment: You – the developer – are responsible to avoid those silly  situations. This is very easy if you consider the naming convention.

Comment: It may be just a question asked of curiosity where the situation is exactly like this. Without a workaround, OOP doesn't permit to have something like `outer.Classname` or `notself.Classname`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't modify the classes, you can embed `ClassA` class into a struct and call it in `classB` like: `StructName.ClassA()`:

```
struct Namespace {
    class ClassA { }
}

class ClassB {

    func ClassA() -> Bool {
       return true
    }

    var test = Namespace.ClassA()
}
```

Comment: @SameeraChandimal Please consider selecting Correct Answer if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can call method by using "self" keyword (and of course, call ClassA function from another function). But you can not create ClassA instance within ClassB. Try refactoring function names within current conventions. As a workaround use Thedore's answer.

```
class ClassA {

}

class ClassB {

    func ClassA() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func something() -> Bool {
        let a = self.ClassA()
        return a

    }

}

var b = ClassB()
var c = b.ClassA()
var d = b.something()
```

Comment: "So how can we create a instance from classA within classB?". You are not responding correctly to the question.